# Suggest a free HTML5 graph Library based on responsive design which can be used on different resolutions?

Tags: html, responsive-design

HTML5 graph Library based on responsive design which can be used on different resolutions? Please Suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `highcharts.js` with good luck: [www.highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com/). It's free for non-commercial use, and you can style it to be used on different resolutions. I've used it with a responsive design before, and it worked well.